# Pass a function pointer with an implicit argument C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers, bind

I have some code that interfaces with two external libraries (i.e. things I cant modify). The first library has a function foo with the following declaration

```
template <typename T, typename Tfrom>
foo(Tfrom (T::*function)())
```

e.g. a function pointer that expects a function that returns some type and has no arguments. In my program at run time, I need to access the second external library to enumerate all the possible functions that I will be passing over to the first library. Psuedo code looks something like

```
//grab pointer to class and get all the shared pointers
std::map<int, ::class2:sptr> my_map = _class2_ptr->get_sptrs()
//for every key in the map we have a function that can be called like
for(auto const& k : my_map)
{
   int returnval = k.second->get_data(k.first);
}
```

in other words the function declaration looks something like (and the sptr must be known to access it).

```
int get_data(int)
```

One solution for this is creating template wrappers like so

```
template<int k>
int get_data_template()
{
    return my_map.at(k)->get_data(k);
}
```

However, this won't work because my_map is sized at runtime, and if you attempt to call this template, like:

```
get_data_template<k>();
```

it will only work if k is a const (e.g. see https://ideone.com/EerO9N ) A work around is assuming a max upper limit for the # of entries we enumerate, and then use template recursion to make the for loop compiletime - but this is horrible...

So - how can I pass the wrapper function over as a function pointer - at runtime/dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried creating a wrapper class? Edit: I still don't get it... `foo` is taking a pointer to member function, but no pointer to object? How is it going to call that method then?

Comment: Note that `foo` can't call it's argument, it lacks a `T`